# GPIO event monitoring fails on Zero 2

Tags: gpio, libgpiod

On my (first) Raspberry Pi Zero 2, `gpiod_ctxless_event_monitor` (from libgpiod) fails, while identical calls succeed on my other Pi 3 and 4. Is this a limitation of the Zero or does this indicate that something's wrong with my system?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the Zero 2?  Is this a new model?

Comment: The SoC on the  Pi Zero 2W (and indeed ALL the Pi before Pi4) have an identical peripheral module, so there is no reason for differences. There are differences in layout & memory, but without detail of what you are doing it is impossible to say.

Comment: That's what I thought too, thanks @Milliways. I'm just trying to start an event monitor for the rising edge on a GPIO pin, nothing out of the ordinary. I'll see if I can find out more this evening.

Comment: @Milliways The RPi Zero 2W has a different revision code. So any GPIO library that is sensitive to that won't work on the new device.